# An extended version of Poincaré recurrence theorem. Please check my proof of it.

Tags: solution-verification, ergodic-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{F},\mu, T)$ be a dynamical system.

I have tried to prove the following:

**Theorem 1**:
Let function $T:X\rightarrow X$, preserves the probabilistic measure $\mu$. For any set $A$, such $\mu(A)>0$, we have:
$$\mu(\{x\in A: \forall_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\exists_{n \ge N}T^n(x)\in A\})=\mu(A)$$

**"Proof"** Let $B(N) = \{x\in A: \forall_{n \ge N}T^n(x)\notin A\}$. The thesis of theorem is equivalent to:
$$\mu(\{x\in A: \exists_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\forall_{n \ge N}T^n(x)\notin A\})=0$$
But i notice that:
$$\mu(\{x\in A: \exists_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\forall_{n \ge N}T^n(x)\notin A\}) = \mu(\bigcup_{N\in \mathbb{N}}B(N))\le \sum_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\mu(B(N))$$
So it is sufficient to prove, that for every $N$ we have $\mu(B(N))=0$

Here is how to do this:

Let $n\ge N$ and $x\in B(N)$, we have: $T^{n}(x)\notin B(N)$, and $x\notin T^{-n}(B(N))$, hence $B(N)\cap T^{-n}(B(N))=\emptyset$

Now
$$\emptyset =T^{-k}(\emptyset)= T^{-k}(T^{-n}(B(N))\cap B(N)) = T^{-k-n}(B(N))\cap T^{-k}(B(N))$$

I can see now, that sets of the form $T^{-n}(B(N))$ are pairwise disjoint and $\mu(T^{-n}(B(N)))=\mu(B(N))$

Now assume that $\mu(B(N))>0$, then

$$\mu(\bigcup_{n\ge N}T^{-n}(B(N)))=\sum_{n\ge N}\mu(T^{-n}(B(N)))=\sum_{n\ge N}\mu(B(N))=\infty$$

A contradiction, since $\mu(X)=1$

> Did i do this proof correctly or no? If no, then please point me where i did something wrong.

Regards

Comment: The proof is correct.